# Не видно блок position:absolute

Tags: html, css

Есть боковое меню интернет-магазина с списком основных категорий, нужно сделать, что бы при наведение на категорию справа показывались подкатегории, но когда я им задаю position:absolute блок не видно на странице, хотя инспектор показывает, что блок есть. Реализовано на первых двух пунктах меню.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.sidebar {
    margin-right: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 29rem;
}

.sidebar__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #EFF0F2;
    padding-bottom: .2rem;
}

.btn-sidebar {
    width: 14.4rem;
    padding: 1rem 2.75rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: #EFF0F2;
}

.btn-sidebar:hover, .btn-sidebar.act {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    background-color: #444A51;
    color: #FAFAFB;
}

.btn-sidebar i {
    margin-right: .5rem;
}

.sidebar__group__title {
    padding: 1.2rem 2rem;
    background-color: #292c31;
    color: #FAFAFB;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sidebar__group-item {
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar__group-item:hover > .sidebar__subnav {
    display: block;
}

.sidebar__subnav {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 40rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: #292c31;
}

.sidebar__subnav li a {
    color: #292c31;
}

.list-hover-slide li {
    background-color: #444A51;
    border-top: 1px solid #7B8591;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list-hover-slide a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #FAFAFB;
    padding: 1.2rem 2rem;
    transition: .35s ease color;
}

.list-hover-slide a:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: solid 5px #E30016;
    background: #5F6871;
    transition: .35s ease left;
}

.list-hover-slide a.is-current, .list-hover-slide a:hover {
    color: #FAFAFB;
}

.list-hover-slide a.is-current:before, .list-hover-slide a:hover:before {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar__btn">
        <a class="btn-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>Фильтры</a>
        <a class="btn-sidebar act"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>Каталог</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar__list">
        <div class="sidebar__group">
            <h3 class="sidebar__group__title">кровельные материалы (223)</h3>
            <ul class="list-hover-slide unstyled">
                <li class="sidebar__group-item">
                    <a href="#">Композитная черепица (подменю)</a> 
                    <ul class="sidebar__subnav">
                        <li><a href="#">Композитная черепица Tilcor Antica (6)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Композитная черепица Tilcor Antica (6)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Композитная черепица Tilcor Antica (6)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar__group-item">
                <a href="#">Композитная черепица (подменю)</a>
                <ul class="sidebar__subnav">
                        <li><a href="#">Композитная черепица Tilcor Antica (6)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Композитная черепица Tilcor Antica (6)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Композитная черепица Tilcor Antica (6)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li class="sidebar__group-item"><a href="#">Композитная черепица (123)</a> </li>
                <li class="sidebar__group-item"><a href="#">Композитная черепица (123)</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- END SIDEBAR GROUP -->
    </div>

</aside>
```

Comment: В .list-hover-slide li есть overflow:hidden; он и скрывает.